# Calling one out of multiple variables from method outside or inside of class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, list-comprehension

I tried looking but couldn't find an answer.

this is my code -

```
class abcd():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def call_from_method_1(self):
        self.a = "value of variable a"
        self.b = 'value of variable b'
        print(self.a + ',', self.b)

    def call_from_method_2(self):
        self.c = 'var c'
        self.d = 'var d'

    def call_specific_variable_from_each_method(self):
        return abcd().call_from_method_1()               # in this line how do I call just the variable b
        return abcd().call_from_method_2()               # and in this line call just d

if True:
    abcd().call_specific_variable_from_each_method()         #so I could print them both in this line
```

I need to call JUST the variable b from `def call_from_method_1(self):` and JUST the variable d from `def call_from_method_2(self):`
and call them into `def call_specific_variable_from_each_method(self):`.
I also have to keep both methods intact if possible so if I instantiate the methods it also prints out `print(self.a + ',', self.b)` from `call_from_method_1(self):` which is not desired.

As mentioned both methods have to be intact and still print just a specific variable from either method outside of the class without having to completely run both methods by instantiating them.

Also as a bonus how do I use if statement in list comprehension to finally call the class?
so I tried
`abcd().call_specific_variable_from_each_method() if True`
but doesn't work. Any Ideas?

It would really help if the solution is not a workaround. But I'm open to whatever solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't going to work as-is.

Firstly, you need to instantiate the class `abcd` in order to call the methods.

Secondly, in `call_specific_variable_from_each_method(self):` you return the abcd()... calls.  They are just going to return None.  You haven't returned anything in any of the methods.  Thirdly, this call returns the first None only.

```
class abcd():

    def __init__(self):
        self.call_from_method_1()
        self.call_from_method_2()

    def call_from_method_1(self):
        self.a = "value of variable a"
        self.b = 'value of variable b'
        return self.b

    def call_from_method_2(self):
        self.c = 'var c'
        self.d = 'var d'
        return self.d

    def call_specific_variable_from_each_method(self):
        return self.call_from_method_1(), self.call_from_method_2()


abcd_obj = abcd()
b, d = abcd_obj.call_specific_variable_from_each_method()
print(b, d)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Definitely learned some bits. However,
if you look at my code certain lines have to be intact including the `print(self.a + ',', self.b)` line in `call_from_method_1`. 
My code asks for call_from_method_1 and call_from_method_2 to be absolutely intact. 
When I use your solution it works but it also prints out a, b from call_from_method_1 which is not desired. comment continued...

Comment: As mentioned both methods have to be intact and still be able to print
 just a specific variable from either method outside of the class without 
 having to completely run both methods by instantiating them.Your code works
  but I just need to fetch out one variable from the method rather than running the whole method.

Comment: in your original code, it prints out self.a, self.b.  now you're saying it's not desired?  I'm confused.

Comment: i thought I understood your question; but with the clarifications, I'm not entirely sure that I answered anything.  Will delete this answer as it's not answering your question.

Comment: I did learn some bits from your answer but it definitely didn't entirely solve my problem. I edited the question for you to make sense. And I am calling to print self.a, self.b in another file so I need that print statement. And I also need to get one variable from it without having to use/run the whole function/method. Is it even possible to do just that?

Comment: As mentioned the print statement has to be intact in second method which isn't reflected in your updated answer. Appreciate it  anyway though.